# Facebook-Android SDK: pause execution until response from user/fb is received

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-android-sdk

I have this chunk of code(below) from a example facebook provides on how to request publish permissions from a user, only problem is that when the chunk of code that causes the fb dialog to pop up and ask a user "would you like to give this app publish permissions?" is called the app continues to execute the code below(a asynctask api request in this case) This is a problem bc fb doesn't really give me a boolean or any other way to check if( the user approved the permission request && the permission was successfully granted) {

execute asynctask api request to update db

}

maybe im missing something or really dumb , but is this not horriable implementation on their part? isnt it pretty standard that any professional publicly used api should return a boolean , a string ...SOMETHING that i can use to create a if statement?!?

```
private void turnOnFacebookPublishing() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            Log.i("sharedprefs fbPublishBool at start of turnOnFbPublish", String.valueOf(sharedprefs.isFacebookPublishingOn()));
            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            Log.i("permissions prior to if", permissions.toString());
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

            }

// asynctask api request to my api that updates a record on my db that determines a users Facebook publishing preference goes here
             }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get a response.

1. Attach a Session.Callback to the session object via session.addCallback().
2. Attach a Session.Callback to the newPermissionsRequest via newPermissionsRequest.setCallback()

Then you override the onActivityResult method in your activity or fragment to call Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult, and your callback will get called.

The reason we need a callback rather than returning some data directly is because this is an asynchronous operation (it creates an intent to start another activity), so we won't know the result until it comes back via onActivityResult.